# T-SQL - Indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a fairly large table (roughly 18 million records), when querying from this table we always include the `AccountId`, an account can hold between 50k to 2million records and we typically query based on `SalesRep` or `CollectionsRep` (rarely both at the same time).

When applying indexes to this table, which would be more appropriate?

- Custered SyntheticColumnId
- Non-Clustered AccountId, SalesRepId
- Non-Clustered AccountId, CollectionsRepId

or

- Clustered SyntheticColumnId
- Non-Clustered AccountId
- Non-Clustered SalesRepId
- Non-Clustered CollectionsRepId

Thanks,

-- editing per billinkc's question in comment.

This is a stage table and is truncated/refreshed daily. I didn't mention this because I was curious in general. And wasn't sure if we had many other common fields that are used in the query if we should use `AccountId` in each.

For this table, the reason I want indexes is to speed up later aggregation prior to pushing to production. Previously the jobs were taking 20-30 minutes but after the indexes (first example) they dropped to under a minute.

- Version - 10.0.4000.0
- Product Level - SP2
- Edition - Enterprise Edition (64-bit)

Comment: What about when you're adding rows? How frequently is that done? What's your rate of change? Are updates performed? Are you Standard Edition or Enterprise Edition? `SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS ProductLevel
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition;`

Comment: As billinkc hints at, adding indexes isn't always a good thing.  Indexes speed up your reads but reduce your update and insert capabilities.

Comment: *‘we typically query based on `SalesRep` or `CollectionsRep` (rarely both at the same time)’* – are both columns allowed to be populated at the same time for the same row?

Comment: And is a typical query like: `SELECT AccountId, other columns FROM table WHERE SalesRepId = 4789;` or like `SELECT columns FROM table WHERE AccountId = 17 AND SalesRepId = 4789;`

Answer (score 2):

Your first choice of indexes is the correct choice.  You say that you are always using `AccountId` in the queries.  Hence, it should be in the index with the other fields.  This will allow the index to directly access the rows that it needs to for your queries.

The second set of indexes only offer partial coverage of the rows.  If they are used, then SQL Server will have to go back to the data pages to get additional information for filtering.

Comment: This keeps getting downvoted without comments.  Would anyone care to share the reason why?  The question is about two sets of possible indexes and a description of the queries, so I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: I'm not a down voter, but I do disagree with your response. For one, order of columns matters, so having the AccountId as the first column in the index will prevent the index from being used at all to locate the rows based on SalesRepId or CollectionsRepId. Also, including AccountId in the index will not help anything unless that is the only column needing to be returned, so the index becomes a covering index. It almost sounds like you misread the usage of AccountId. The original question did not mention filtering by AccountId.

Comment: @shriop actually it does: *"when querying from this table we **always** include the AccountId"*. The meaning of *"include"* in that phrase can have various interpretations.